# Как создать кастомный роутинг в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, маршрутизация

Я создал кастомный роутинг по произвольным ссылкам как в этом решении https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611863/net-mvc-4-routing-with-custom-slugs. Данное решение подразумевает, что из базы будет выбрана страница по урлу и в этом объекте будет название контроллера и метода, куда надо будет перенаправить запрос. У меня есть проблема, я не знаю, как вызывать другие методы контроллера, кроме Index (например, он указан в БД). Как мне определить, что урл, который ко мне пришёл - это не адрес страницы, а метод, который надо вызвать у этой страницы?

Comment: Вопрос в том как распарсить строку которую Вы получаете из БД? 
Или как вызывать другие методы контроллера, кроме Index?

Comment: Вопрос, как вызвать другие методы, кроме Index

Comment: Вместо Index напишите имя метода который вы хотите вызвать. Для более подробных объяснений приведите код, где у Вас не получается вызвать метод.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, как мне узнать, что урл, который ко мне пришёл - это вызов метода, а не ссылка, которую надо найти в БД. Код - по ссылке в вопросе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611863/net-mvc-4-routing-with-custom-slugs.

Comment: В примере БД хранит ActionName это и есть метод контроллера. Как вы храните URL  в базе ? Просто как строку? Или как в вашем примере ActionName, ControllerName и т.д.?

Comment: Храню точно так же, как в примере.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы сделали так же как примере то вам из базы не приходит Url, а структура URL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из вашей ссылки:

`GetPageByFriendlyUrl` принимает как параметр `url` который будет передан далее   в запросе к БД.

БД нам вернет `PageItem` который соответсвует переданному в запросе `url`

`PageItem.ActionName` содержит название метода вашего контроллера который нужно вызвать

`PageItem.ControllerName` содержит название вашего контроллера

```
    PageItem page = RedirectManager.GetPageByFriendlyUrl(url);
                if (page != null)
                {
                    FillRequest(page.ControllerName, 
                        page.ActionName ?? "GetStatic", 
                        page.ID.ToString(), 
                        requestContext);
                }
```

P.S. конечно класс `PageItem`вам нужно где-то объявить. `GetPageByFriendlyUrl` тоже нужно переписать.

Comment: Я всё и реализовал подобным образом, храню название контроллера и экшона. Меня интересует, как вызывать какой-либо другой метод контроллера.
Например, в БД есть запись Home/Index. И я по алиасу страницы выбираю эту строку из базы, перехожу на нужную мне страницу, всё круто. А теперь на этой странице есть ссылка, например 'GetAllЧтоТоТам'. При клике на неё у меня произойдёт вызов всё того же куска кода, который ищет страницу по алиасу. **Но мне это уже не нужно! Мне уже надо вызвать метод контроллера текущей страницы!** Вот в чём мой вопрос, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Итак, у вас есть контент, и вы храните его в базе данных. Вы написали кастомный роутинг, который позволяет возвращать страницы из базы данных, когда юзер ходит по вашему сайту. Но при этом вы хотите продолжить использовать и стандартный роутинг ASP.MVC параллельно с кастомным роутингом.

Ключ к решению проблемы - посмотреть на роутинг извне. Представьте, что механизм роутинга это черный ящик, и мы не знаем, как он реализован. В этом случае мы можем сказать о его работе следующее: на *вход* он получает url, а на *выходе* возвращает один из стандартных ответов веб-сайта - html-страницу, json и т.д.

Значит единственная информация, на основании которой механизм роутинга может принять решение о том, каким должен быть ответ - это url, который он получает. То есть вы в уме знаете, что маршрут `Home/Index` должен вернуть страницу из бд, а маршрут `Home/GetAllProducts` должен вызвать метод контроллера, но механизм роутинга этого не знает, и единственное место, откуда он может об этом узнать, это url, который он получает на вход.

То есть критерий, по которому вы решаете, что брать из базы, а что обрабатывать контроллером должен быть выражен *непосредственно в url*, в нем должен быть какой то сегмент или параметр, который явно будет указывать какой вариант обработки маршрута надо использовать. Как только вы определитесь с этим критерием, вам останется лишь настроить механизм роутинга на его обработку.

Когда будете определяться с критерием, прежде всего обратите внимание вот на что - довольно странно, что по адресам, начинающимся с `Home/` у вас может находиться и контент из базы и методы конроллера. Скорее всего для методов конроллера нужны отдельные маршруты.

На вашем примере из комментария, если `Home/Index` берет страницу из базы данных, то пусть все остальные маршруты по адресу `Home/` делают тоже самое. А метод `GetAllProducts`, который вы хотели разместить в HomeController'е заслуживает отдельного маршрута. Создайте `ProductController`, пусть все продукты можно будет получить по адресу `Product/GetAll`. И пусть по адресам, начинающимся с  `Product/` будут только методы контроллеров и не будет никаких страниц из бд.

Тогда критерием, по которому вы решаете, что должен быть вызван метод контроллера, является наличие в маршруте слова "Product" в качестве первого сегмента. И тогда вы можете описать роутинг так:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "Product/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "FromDb",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }).RouteHandler = new SlugRouteHandler();
    }
```

Обратите внимание на то, что в первом маршруте вместо переменной `{controller}` указано точное название  контроллера. Маршруты обрабатываются в том порядке, в котором они перечислены, маршруты начинающиеся с `Product/` подходят под первый шаблон `"Product/{action}/{id}"` и будут обработаны по первому правилу, а все остальные маршруты - по второму.

Если у вас немного контроллеров, методы которых вы хотите вызывать, для каждого из них вполне можно создать отдельное правило в методе `RegisterRoutes`.
Главное помните о порядке перечисления маршрутов.

Кроме того вы можете использовать большее количество сегментов, и сделать один из сегментов статичным. Например, если вы сделаете вот так

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "FromDb",
            "Content/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }).RouteHandler = new SlugRouteHandler();

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

то маршруты, начинающиеся с `Content` будут возвращать страницы из бд, а все остальные будут обрабатываться стандартным образом. (В этом случае главное не создавать `ContentController`, чтобы не было неоднозначности).

Comment: Отличный ответ! Хотя вряли задавший вопрос еще решает свою проблему.

Comment: @koks_rs спасибо!

Comment: @koks_rs, я уже решил свою проблему. Я создал свой MvcRouteHandler и в нём написал код, который пытается найти по указанной ссылке страницу в БД, и если находит, то отправляет этот объект в контроллер, а если нет - то на 404. Я создал функционал CMS системы с произвольными урлами.

Comment: @koks_rs, Проблема, которую я пытался тут описать - как мне вызывать **ДРУГИЕ** методы контроллера, кроме как Index. Я решил, что просто буду делать их AJAX'ом, это можно узнать свойством HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAjaxRequest().